# Mockito - mocked static method always returns null

Tags: java, mockito

Hi All i am trying to mock a static method. Below is my sample class looks like.

```
public class UserHandler{
public User create(Request request)
User user = UserUtil.create(dbs, dba, jo, user);
return user;
}
```

this is my test class code

```
try(MockedStatic<UserUtil> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(UserUtil.class)) {
        Mockito.when(UserUtil.create(mockDBS, mockAdmin, obj, user)).thenReturn(user);
        User response = handler.create(mockZrequest);
        assertEquals(res, response);
}
```

But unfortunately i am keep on getting response as Null. Someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the `MockedStatic` instance and a lambda for mocking static methods:

```
try(MockedStatic<MyUtilsClass> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(MyUtilsClass.class)) {
    // Use mockedStatic.when() for mocking, NOT Mockito.when(): 
    mockedStatic.when(

        // Use a lambda inside when(), NOT a direct method invocation:
        () -> MyUtilsClass.myStaticMethod(param1, param2)

    ).thenReturn(
        mockedReturnValue
    );
}
```

in your case it would be:

```
try(MockedStatic<UserUtil> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(UserUtil.class)) {
    mockedStatic.when(() -> UserUtil.create(mockDBS, mockAdmin, obj, user)).thenReturn(user);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Alex still getting null as my response.
try(MockedStatic<UserUtil> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(UserUtil.class)) {
    mockedStatic.when(() -> UserUtil.create(mockDBS, mockAdmin, obj, user)).thenReturn(user);
    ZResponse response = handler.create(mockZrequest);
    assertEquals(res, response);
   }

Comment: Alex thank you for your help. I tried with below 
mockedStatic.when(() -> UserUtil.create(Mockito.any(DBSession.class ), Mockito.any(DBAdmin.class ), Mockito.any(JSONObject.class ), Mockito.any(User.class ))).thenReturn(user);

it worked.